# Need to issue multiple HTTP Get requests from single connection

Tags: .net, http

Unfortunately, can't use the 4.5 framework HttpClient class as that should work just fine.

I need to get results from a website that requires authentification in the URI. The first time you use HTTP GET, it always fails with a 401 (authentification failed) error. The 2nd time you use HTTP GET it works -- verified this used browser and Fiddler.

My problem is, I can't figure out how to issue multiple HTTP GET on a given socket using either the System.Net.WebClient or System.NetWebRequest classes.

```
Both of these appear to be designed to support only a single Get/Response pair

// via WebRequest

System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(xc.InspectionURL);
System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse(); // throws 401 exception

// via WebClient

System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
Stream data = wc.OpenRead(xc.InspectionUrl); // throws 401 exception
```

The 401 exceptions are of the type System.Net.WebException

I've attempted a retry on the after the exception to retry both the "contructor equivalents" and the GetResponse() equivalent, but I still get the 401 error on the retry.

Once the initial request succeeds (with authentification) I need to make a number of additional request using the same connection too, so I would like to avoid total kludges, and I would obviously like to avoid writing everything from something low level like the System.Net.Sockets

Is there some method or other class that I have overlooked?. Or a recommended 3rd party library? I've used [Indy components](http://www.indyproject.org/SocketsCLR/index.EN.aspx) before, but their CLR version seems to be less than complete.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I kept digging around and found that I could use RestSharp to issue multiple GETs. RestSharp supports .Net 3.5 & 4.0 -- so I am good to go.